# Setting up Elasticsearch and Ruby on Rails in CircleCI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, circleci

I am trying to setup CircleCI with Elasticsearch in my Rails application. I think have the image configured, but how do I connect to it in CI?

So far I have tried...

https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/23866

**Error Message**

```
Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::Unauthorized: [401]
```

**Circle YAML Config**

```
version: 2
jobs:
  build:
    working_directory: ~/gathrly-smartforms
    docker:
      - image: circleci/ruby:2.4.1-node
        environment:
          RAILS_ENV: continous_integration
          PGHOST: 127.0.0.1
          PGUSER: rails_test_user

      - image: circleci/postgres:9.6.3-alpine
        environment:
          POSTGRES_USER: rails_test_user
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ""
          POSTGRES_DB: continous_integration

      - image: redis:4.0.2
      - image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.4.2

    steps:
      - checkout

      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - my-application-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
            - my-application-

      - save_cache:
          key: rails-demo-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - vendor/bundle

      - run:
          name: Setup Bundler and Gems
          command: |
            gem install bundler
            gem update bundler
            gem install brakeman
            gem install rubocop
            gem install rubocop-rspec
            gem install scss_lint
            gem install eslint-rails
            gem install execjs
            bundle config without development:test
            bundle check --path=vendor/bundle || bundle install --without development test --path=vendor/bundle --jobs 4 --retry 3

      - run:
          name: Setup Postgres
          command: |
            sudo apt-get install postgresql-client

      - run:
          name: Setup Rails Database
          command: |
            RAILS_ENV=continous_integration bundle exec rake db:drop
            RAILS_ENV=continous_integration bundle exec rake db:setup

      - run:
          name: Run Rspec
          command: |
            RAILS_ENV=continous_integration bundle exec rspec --format RspecJunitFormatter -o /tmp/test-results/rspec.xml

      - store_test_results:
          path: /tmp/test-results
```

**Elastic Search Initializer**

```
require 'faraday_middleware/aws_signers_v4'

if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.staging?
  Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(url: ENV["AWS_ELASTICSEARCH_HOST"]) do |f|
    f.request :aws_signers_v4,
      credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'], ENV['AWS_ACCESS_SECRET_KEY']),
      service_name: 'es',
      region: ENV['AWS_REGION']

    f.adapter Faraday.default_adapter
  end
else
  config = {
    host: "http://127.0.0.1:9200",
    transport_options: {
      request: { timeout: 5 }
    }
  }
  if File.exists?("config/elasticsearch.yml")
    config.merge!(YAML.load_file("config/elasticsearch.yml"))
  end

  Elasticsearch::Model.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(config)
end
```

Comment: Hi Chris. If you have answer material, please always add it as a self-answer below, rather than merging it with the question. There's an "Answer your own question" button for the purpose.

Comment: Also, I notice that your question titles are formed of lower-case tag lists. The community generally prefers titles to be fully-formed English sentences, using the appropriate case rules for readability. I find titles as questions work well, but I don't think that's mandatory. [Read my community answer here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253076/472495) for more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official docker images from elastic come with x-pack preinstalled.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/docker.html

That means that your elasticsearch instance is running with security enabled, but you do not appear to be providing any security credentials to your elasticsearch client, and so you get an unauthorised (`401`) error when you try to connect.

You should either turn off security in your ES instance by adding
`xpack.security.enabled: false` to your `elasticsearch.yml`, or provide valid credentials in your request.

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the question author)*.

From the other answer provided:

```
development: &default
  host: 'http://localhost:9200/'
  transport_options:
    request:
      timeout: !!integer 300

test:
  <<: *default

staging:
  <<: *default

continous_integration:
  <<: *default
  xpack.security.enabled: false
```